# "null" printed infinitely when client logs out of chat program

Tags: java

When two (or more) clients are connected to the server, when I press `logout` for one of the clients, he successfully disconnects. However, the other client(s) get `"null"` printed on their text area(s) infinitely, so it keeps printing `"null"` without stoping.

```
  public void run(){
        if (socket != null && reader != null) {
            try {
                String in;
                while (keepGoing){
                    try{
                        in= reader.readLine();
                        send(in+"\n");  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** this is not an error, but a bug so I don't get any exceptions.

Comment: Sounds like `reader` is connected to the incoming socket stream, which has closed, so `readLine() returns `null`,  which you then print out on the very next line.  Once `null` has been returned, there is no point in looping back and calling `readLine()` again - the end of the stream has been encountered.

Comment: @AJNeufeld you mean the `socket != null` part? I commented that `if` statement out (only the condition, not the whole thing) and I still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like the following:

```
while (messageLoop){
    try{
        messageInput = reader.readLine();

        if(messageInput == null) break;

        sendMessage(messageInput+"\n");  

    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){
        Thread.yield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are reading from the reader infinitely even when there is nothing left to read. You can do the following to correct the code:

```
public void run(){
    if (socket != null && reader != null) {
        try {
            String in;
            while (keepGoing){
                if(reader != null){
                    try{
                        in= reader.readLine();
                        send(in+"\n");  
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        //Exception thrown, do something about it
                    }
                }
                else{
                      // nothing to read, do something else
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```